# How to add source files from another directory in a cmake file?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to write a `CMakeLists.txt` file for the `test/` directory in a project I'm working on. The directory tree for `test/` is

```
test/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── data_handlers.o
├── Makefile
├── run_tests.cpp
├── test_data
│   ├── QLD.csv
│   └── SPY.csv
├── test_data_handler.cpp
├── test_data_reader.cpp
├── test_exec_handler.cpp
├── test_fill.cpp
├── test_instrument.cpp
├── test_market_bar.cpp
├── test_market_snapshot.cpp
├── test_order.cpp
├── test_pnl_calculator.cpp
├── test_portfolio.cpp
└── test_position_summary.cpp
```

The unusual thing that I'm doing is all of the source files that these tests are testing are not compiled as a library, and that directory has its own `CMakeLists.txt`, too.  So this cmake file that belongs to `test/` has to compile and link those guys too. However, I get a million `undefined reference` errors, and it can't find things that were defined outside of this `test/` directory.

Here's `test/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(markets_tests)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/g++-8)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE OFF)

find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
find_package(UnitTest++ REQUIRED)

SET(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-no-pie")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")

include_directories(
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include"
        ${UTPP_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )


file(GLOB all_SRCS
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/data_handlers.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/data_readers.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/data_execution_handler.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/fill.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/instrument.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/market_bar.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/market_snapshot.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/model_bank.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/order.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/pnl_calculator.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/portfolio.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/position_summary.cpp"
        )

add_executable(run_tests ${all_SRCS})
target_link_libraries (run_tests Eigen3::Eigen stdc++fs UnitTest++)
```

### Edit

Here is the tree for the overall project

```
t@t-XPS-13-9365:~/markets$ tree
.
├── build
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   ├── 3.10.2
│   │   │   ├── CMakeCCompiler.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin
│   │   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin
│   │   │   ├── CMakeSystem.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CompilerIdC
│   │   │   │   ├── a.out
│   │   │   │   ├── CMakeCCompilerId.c
│   │   │   │   └── tmp
│   │   │   └── CompilerIdCXX
│   │   │       ├── a.out
│   │   │       ├── CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
│   │   │       └── tmp
│   │   ├── cmake.check_cache
│   │   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   │   ├── CMakeOutput.log
│   │   ├── CMakeTmp
│   │   ├── feature_tests.bin
│   │   ├── feature_tests.c
│   │   ├── feature_tests.cxx
│   │   ├── Makefile2
│   │   ├── Makefile.cmake
│   │   ├── progress.marks
│   │   ├── run_backtest.dir
│   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CXX.includecache
│   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   ├── depend.internal
│   │   │   ├── depend.make
│   │   │   ├── flags.make
│   │   │   ├── link.txt
│   │   │   ├── progress.make
│   │   │   └── src
│   │   │       ├── data_handlers.cpp.o
│   │   │       ├── data_readers.cpp.o
│   │   │       ├── execution_handler.cpp.o
│   │   │       ├── fill.cpp.o
│   │   │       ├── instrument.cpp.o
│   │   │       ├── main.cpp.o
│   │   │       ├── market_bar.cpp.o
│   │   │       ├── market_snapshot.cpp.o
│   │   │       ├── model_bank.cpp.o
│   │   │       ├── order.cpp.o
│   │   │       ├── pnl_calculator.cpp.o
│   │   │       ├── portfolio.cpp.o
│   │   │       └── position_summary.cpp.o
│   │   └── TargetDirectories.txt
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── run_backtest
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── data
│   ├── QLD.csv
│   └── SPY.csv
├── include
│   ├── data_handlers.h
│   ├── data_readers.h
│   ├── execution_handler.h
│   ├── fill.h
│   ├── instrument.h
│   ├── market_bar.h
│   ├── market_snapshot.h
│   ├── model_bank.h
│   ├── order.h
│   ├── pnl_calculator.h
│   ├── portfolio.h
│   └── position_summary.h
├── README.md
├── scripts
│   └── download_raw_daily_data.r
├── src
│   ├── data_handlers.cpp
│   ├── data_readers.cpp
│   ├── execution_handler.cpp
│   ├── fill.cpp
│   ├── instrument.cpp
│   ├── main.cpp
│   ├── market_bar.cpp
│   ├── market_snapshot.cpp
│   ├── model_bank.cpp
│   ├── order.cpp
│   ├── pnl_calculator.cpp
│   ├── portfolio.cpp
│   └── position_summary.cpp
└── test
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── data_handlers.o
    ├── Makefile
    ├── run_tests.cpp
    ├── test_data
    │   ├── QLD.csv
    │   └── SPY.csv
    ├── test_data_handler.cpp
    ├── test_data_reader.cpp
    ├── test_exec_handler.cpp
    ├── test_fill.cpp
    ├── test_instrument.cpp
    ├── test_market_bar.cpp
    ├── test_market_snapshot.cpp
    ├── test_order.cpp
    ├── test_pnl_calculator.cpp
    ├── test_portfolio.cpp
    └── test_position_summary.cpp
```

### Edit 2

I've tried to take into account the solution proposed below by squareskittles. Here's my `CMakeLists.txt` in the top level directory:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(markets)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/g++-8)
find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
include_directories(
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
)
file(GLOB all_SRCS
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp"
        )
add_executable(run_backtest ${all_SRCS})
add_library(MarketLibrary ${all_SRCS})
add_subdirectory(test)
target_link_libraries (run_backtest Eigen3::Eigen stdc++fs)
```

When I try to `cmake ..` this, it just runs forever.

Comment: Is this `CMakeLists.txt` file part of a larger CMake project? If so, you can reference libraries previously built upstream using CMake variables.

Comment: @squareskittles good idea. see edit

Comment: In your edit, you should move the `add_subdirectory()` to the end. Also, since your top-level CMake sets `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`, you shouldn't have them in the lower-level CMake's. In fact, these should be set before any call to `project()`, which may be why your CMake is hanging... You also only need to `find_package()` for Eigen3 once.

Comment: @squareskittles yes that fixes the hanging, but now it can't find the Eigen headers with `#include <Eigen/Dense>`

Comment: What cannot find the Eigen headers? Your top-level targets? or the tests in the `test/` directory? Were the headers being found before? It is helpful in this circumstance to run `make VERBOSE=1` to turn on additional logging from `make` to determine if the correct Eigen include directories are being passed to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If your top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file creates the library (say, `MarketLibrary`), you can reference it and link it to your test executable in your other CMake files. This should help with the undefined reference errors:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
...
add_library(MarketLibrary
    src/data_handlers.cpp
    src/data_readers.cpp
    ...
)

...

add_subdirectory(test)
```

**test/CMakeLists.txt** (modify your `target_link_libraries()` command):

```
project(markets_tests)

... 

add_executable(run_tests ${all_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(run_tests Eigen3::Eigen stdc++fs UnitTest++ MarketLibrary)
```